# Transparecy in canvas android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to add canvas (somewhat transparent in color) on background which has some image on its `Ontouch` event. I want to remove that transparent color of canvas which makes my background image clear.

I'm using:

```
paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

but nothing is happening on canvas. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

i have added transparent canvas on background...which makes my image above:

and ontouch resultant should be like this:

[image]

Comment: Was this meant as an update to your question, or an answer?